# Sending multiple checkbox values to email through PHPMailer

Tags: php

I have got a PHP test form whereby I get empty values from the selected checkbox fields in my email after hitting submit button. I am using PHPMailer to send inputs to my mail.~ Kindly assist

**PHP PART**

```
// Check the values from checkbox and POST them to email       
If (isset($_POST["checkbox"]) && !empty($_POST["checkbox"]))             
    {
        $checkbox =$_POST["checkbox"];                //Array of values from the checkbox values
            $value= implode(' , ', $checkbox);           //implode values and separate by a comma
                echo $value;
    }                          

else 
    {
        test_input($_POST["value"]);          //POST values to email
    }
```

**PHPMAILER PART**

```
require ("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");                      //Instantiate the Phpmailer class

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";            // main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                     // TLS connection
    $mail->Port = 587;                                //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // turn on SMTP authorization
    $mail->Username = "gmail_address";          //username
    $mail->Password = "****************";            // password

    $mail->From = "$email";                         //sender's email
    $mail->FromName = "$name";                        //name
    $mail->AddAddress("gmail_address", "Pettans");        //email address of recepient and name
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);                     //Address to which recepient will reply
    $mail->Subject = "Graphics Design Form";    //subject of email

    $mail->WordWrap = 120;                                   //word wrap to 100 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                          //email format to HTML

    $mail->Body = "<br>Checkbox: " . $_POST["value"];




    if ($valid) {
        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            echo 'Form could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        } else {
            header('Location:thanks.html');
        }
    }
}


function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;

}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<br> <br> What project would you like for your institution? <span class= "error"> * </span>
                   <br> <br> <input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Graphics Design"> Graphics Design (Book, Posters, Flyers, Banners, Magazines, T-Shirts) <br>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Logo Design" > Professional logo Design <br>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="input" name="checkbox[]" value="Branding" > Branding
```

Comment: have you tried using a var_dump after submit to see what gets submitted?

Comment: try print_r($_POST) in PHP part and also show the full form

Comment: @Ann, I get the email with an empty field in the checkbox area

Comment: @coder, could you expound using an example

Comment: the form echoes the fields on my screen and also sends them, but I dont get any value that has been selected

Comment: are your php part and php mailer part in the same page?

Comment: @coder, Yah, they are exactly on the same page

Comment: `$mail->Body = "<br>Checkbox: " . $_POST["value"];`... you never add `$checkbox` to the email body?

Comment: U have never added checkbox value to the email. Thats why its not working

Comment: @Magnus, the checkbox is an array which I have assigned it a variable known as value after using implode then send $value- Check PHP part

Comment: Sure... but then it should be: `$mail->Body = $value`, not `$_POST["value"]`.

Comment: Is there an input with the name `name="value"` in your form, or are you trying to use `$_POST['value']` to access the `$value`-variable you created?

Comment: @Magnus, GREAT !!! You have solved my problem half-way: I have changed  $_POST["value"]. to  $mail->Body = $value and it works. But I don't get the last value from the checkboxes if it is checked

Comment: You have some other issues with your code. I've posted an answer...

Comment: Thank-you very much Magnus Erikson, the code finally gets to work....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to access your variable `$value` by accessing it from the `$_POST`-super global. That won't work...

Here is a rewrite that should do the trick:

```
$value = null; // Define the variable and set a default value

if (isset($_POST["checkbox"])) {
    // empty() is not needed since 'checkbox' won't be sent
    // if none was selected.

    $value = implode(' , ', $_POST['checkbox']);
    $value = test_input($value);

}

require ("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//...the rest of the PHPMailer-setup

$mail->Body = "<br>Checkbox: " . $value;

//...the rest of your script
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats my full PHP code:

```
<?php

        //INITIALIZE VARIABLES
             $checkbox ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {



// Check the values from checkbox and POST them to email       
If (isset($_POST["checkbox"]) && !empty($_POST["checkbox"]))             
    {
        $checkbox =$_POST["checkbox"];                //Array of values from the checkbox values
            $value= implode(' , ', $checkbox);           //implode values and separate by a comma
                echo $value;
    }                          

else 
    {
        test_input($_POST["value"]);          //POST values to email
    }      

    require ("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");                      //Instantiate the Phpmailer class

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";            // main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                     // TLS connection
    $mail->Port = 587;                                //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // turn on SMTP authorization
    $mail->Username = "gmail_address";          //username
    $mail->Password = "****************";            // password

    $mail->From = "$email";                         //sender's email
    $mail->FromName = "$name";                        //name
    $mail->AddAddress("gmail_address", "Pettans");        //email address of recepient and name
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);                     //Address to which recepient will reply
    $mail->Subject = "Graphics Design Form";    //subject of email

    $mail->WordWrap = 120;                                   //word wrap to 100 characters
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                          //email format to HTML

    $mail->Body = "<br>Checkbox: " . $_POST["value"];




    if ($valid) {
        if (!$mail->Send()) {
            echo 'Form could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        } else {
            header('Location:thanks.html');
        }
    }
}


function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;

}

?>
```